# What is runZonedGuarded in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

I am integrating Crashlytics in my Flutter app and the sample code suggest use of runZonedGuarded. I was trying to understand what it is and how does it effect app stability and performance.

Answer (score 5):

see link below for detailed explanation on the benefits of **runZonedGuarded** *by Fred Grott*. As I understand it, runZonedGuarded essentially provides better traceability for errors, exceptions and debugging...
[Mastering Flutter Zones](https://medium.com/geekculture/mastering-flutter-zones-ea28fe6a6ca6)

As one example, it can be used as follows:

```
void main {    
    runZonedGuarded(
        () => runApp(App()),
        (error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace),
      );
}
```